# tailing aws lambda/cloudwatch logs

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, tail

Found out how to access lambda logs from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846959/how-do-you-look-at-console-log-output-of-the-amazon-lambda-function)

Is it possible to tail them? (manually pressing refresh is cumbersome)

Comment: If you are using the Serverless Framework you can get the tail log entry from command line itself for a particular function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Since you mentioned `tail`-ing, I'm expecting that you are comfortable with working on the terminal with CLI tools.*

You can install [`awslogs`](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) locally and use it to `tail` Cloudwatch.

e.g.

```
$ awslogs get /aws/lambda/my-api-lambda ALL --watch --profile production
```

Aside from not needing to refresh anything anymore (that's what `tail` is for), I also like that you don't have to worry about jumping between different LogGroups (unlike in the CloudWatch console).

Answer (score 2):

**Aside:** We've noticed that tailing logs gets really slow after an AWS Lambda Function has had a lot of invocations. Even looking at logs through the AWS Console is incredibly slow. This is because "tail" type utilities need to connect to each log stream. Log events get expired due to the policy you set on the Log Group itself, but the Log Streams never get cleaned up. I made a few little utility scripts to help with that:

https://github.com/four43/aws-cloudwatch-log-clean

Hopefully that save you some agony over waiting for those logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the awscli

From the command line you can also do:

`aws logs tail <your_log_group_name> --follow`

The `--follow` flag will pull for new logs continuously

You can also use `--since` to set from what time to begin displaying logs

It supports:

`s - seconds`

`m - minutes`

`h - hours`

`d - days`

`w - weeks`

i.e

`aws logs tail <your_log_group_name> --since 20m`

Comment: how to disable --follow option? i don't want to run continuously .

Comment: @alireza You can just remove the follow from the command and include the `--since` options to scope the logs that you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a better way with Insights (in the same CloudWatch).

Run query like on a log group and you will get what you want:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

You can also add it to Dashboard to always have it "nearby"